# skin the dropdownbox

Tags: apache-flex, drop-down-menu

i am wondering if there is a way to skin the whole drop down box, after searching Google i could only find thing like adding icons resizing and alike, but no full skinning of the box.

Is this at all possible and if so how? i would very much like my whole program to be skinned  rather than everything but the drop down boxes.

I am more of a designer than a coder so as far as code goes I'm quite a novice with the code side, would be a great help if you could give me a point in the right direction and/or a quick insight how to do it.

in flex... sorry

Thanks.

Comment: which language, designer, web or forms? Dropdown box for what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i am wondering if there is a way to skin the whole drop down box,

Yes, create a custom skin class for the [DropDownList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff92-59bf082612135c9e688-7fff.html), just like you would any other Spark class.  You can use code for the [DropDownListSkin](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/skins/spark/DropDownListSkin.html) as a reference point for creating your own.  In Flash Builder, if you create a new MXML Skin; and specify the hostComponent as a DropDownList then you'll get the DropDownListSkin code as a starter point for your customization.

For more info, read these docs on skinning [Spark Components](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSA95C9644-B650-4783-B5C0-D2C7F95A23E3.html).

We did, in essence, exactly this to create our [Mobile DropDownList](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=21).